# Create Shortcut to Files in my MicroSD Automatically

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, sd-card, micro-sd-card

Some days ago, I got a problem with my Micro SD. The problem is this: 
When I connect my Micro SD to PC, and when I went to its drive, i can not see anythings there. Just there is a Shortcut with the below Target :

```
C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe _WYMGAZLE.init,krnl pubrxdiotaqvchnszpuf intkps
```

When i goes to this target,I can see and use my files! and there is a System Folder in my MicroSD Called " " (Just a Character) and when i goes to this folder i can use my files to.
Also I fully Formatted my MicroSD but still this problem exist !

**My Question:**

 How can I Fix my MicroSD "Shortcut" problem?

Comment: You still see a shortcut on the card even after formatting it? Try deleting all partitions via Disk Management (or via `diskpart / select disk / clean`), then create a new one, format and see if the problem persists.

Comment: How can i use "diskpart" ? i tried Disk Management and when i tried to delete my Micro SD Partition, i see it was not Available to delete it.

Comment: From an elevated/admin cmd prompt: `1. diskpart 2. list disk 3. select disk <number> 4. clean`. If that doesn't work use a Linux system or LiveCD/USB and wipe the drive using GParted. As suggested below also be sure to scan your PC for malware.

Comment: @Karan : I cleaned it, and then made a new volume (simple), but it didn't fixed! still I have shortcut problem.

Comment: Also you could try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which performs pretty detailed monitoring (so you will probaly need to play with filtering rules for a while)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect a Trojan or a rootkit could be placing the files back.

Look for an anti-virus Live CD (at teast two major companies provide them for free) and scan your system when booted from it, including the MicroSD card.

Comment: No, there is no any Trojan or Rootkit.

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri Impressive, indeed.  Do I assume correctly that you have already performad the scan?  I thought that point in rootkits is that they are invisible for the system being compromised.  Obviously 4 years in AV testing is not enough to grow a super-power. ;)

Comment: I Scanned my PC Using 3 kind of different anti-viruses. [Kasper,Bitdef,Avast]. I was sure that there is no any malwares in my computer because i never connect it (my another computer) to Internet, any USB and etc, i have 2 kind of firewall (windows-firewall) and one Kaspersky (Pro edition) and some other security softwares. so i'm sure there is no malwares in it! But i don't know why this Happened! I do anythings to fix it but i could't :( !!

Comment: Regarding using different AVs/Firewalls on the same machine, don't expect that it will increase security.  In fact, it's rather the opposite, since the different components can collide in each other (not every AV provider is willing to test their product with competition, and if hey do, they can only care if their one works).  Also I'm confused about the part with not connecting any USB: You do connect the card, do you?

Comment: I Just connect my MicroSD (i had same problem in other machines before connecting it to this machine!) Also i fully scanned it (inclouding my MicroSD and all of my data). but i have same problem !

Comment: Anyway, note that if there is rootkit on your machine, chances are that at the moment your OS is booted normally, nothing that is running on it will be able to detect the activity since RK appends to the very functions that are used for the detection (kind of a chicken-egg problem).  Running scan from booted Live CD avoids this problem completely.

Comment: Ok, i'll test it. just note that i do the same things (like scan, format, ...) from "safe mode startup" and "safe Bootup". but i have the problem !